# Perl: How do I read a text file word by word starting at a particular pattern?

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm trying to write a script that reads a space-delimited text file and recognizes a certain pattern `PATTERN`. After recognizing `PATTERN`, the script should read `RANDOM_NUMBER` of words starting at `PATTERN`. For example, suppose `PATTERN` is `a` and `RANDOM_NUMBER` is `7`. Then for this text file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b c d e f 
g h i j k j
```

I would want to get:

```
a b c d e f
g
```

as output.

So far, I've gotten to the point of recognizing these patterns, but I don't know how to handle it afterwards. What is the best way to read in the words?

By the way, I've looked at [Read text file in Perl word by word instead of line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668853/read-text-file-in-perl-word-by-word-instead-of-line-by-line) and it's a little too vague for my purposes. Also, the answers do not provide much explanation in terms of what the code is doing.

Comment: You could read the whole file into a string buffer and split it into words afterwards using regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so the trick here is to set `$/` - the record separator. If we set it to `' '` we can iterate one 'word' at a time.

Then we can use the range operator to 'detect' if we are between our patterns.

```
local $/ = ' ';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    if ( m/a/ ..  10 ) { print; }
}
```

Now, this prints *from* a to "field 10" - which isn't particularly helpful, because that "count" starts at the start of the file. (By

So instead we probably want to 'trigger' when the seen condition is true, and continue for a number of other iterations:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ' ';

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m/a/) {
        print;
        for ( 2 .. 7 ) { print scalar <DATA>; } #2 because we already have "1"
        last; #assuming we only want to do this once. 
    }
}


__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5 6 
a b c d e f 
g h i j k j
```

Which prints:

```
a b c d e f 
g
```

Comment: Okay, suppose my file is very large--wouldn't it be very slow to read it word by word starting at the beginning? Is there a way to read line by line until the pattern is found, then read word by word? Also, could you clarify what you mean by 'continue for a number of other iterations'? Wouldn't `for (1 .. 7) { print scalar <DATA>; }` also start at the beginning of the file? Thanks!

Comment: input is buffered, so it's a moot point. The actual reads from disk are in larger chunks. But you could set `$/` after the pattern match - doubt it'll make much difference. Just bear in mind that you've _already_ read the whole line `a b c d e f`.  Reading `<DATA>` continues from where it last left off.

Comment: Maybe [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) could be used to bypass the buffering?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Buffering is a good thing. You read from disk at least a sector at a time, and probably a 1k block. This means that it is the same number of IO operations regardless of whether your script is "reading" a byte or a line.

Comment: I've realized now that setting `local $/ = ' ';` is not good for my purposes. If I run the above code, it will give me `a b c d e f\ng h` since it doesn't account for the newline following `g`, thus counting `f\ng` as one word. How can I circumvent this problem?